# What plant is this, seen at the Allan Gardens?

Tags: botany, species-identification, flowers

I tried a couple of apps on my phone, but I could not identify this flower and plant species.  These are at the
[Allen Gardens Conservatory](http://torontobotanicalgarden.ca/get-gardening/public-gardens/allan-gardens/), at the beginning of Spring in Toronto.

[image: these are at Allen Gardens Conservatory, at the beginning of Spring in Toronto]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a *Schizanthus* "orchid" (actually not a real orchid) called [***Schizanthus pinnatus***](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schizanthus#Schizanthus_pinnatus_Ruiz_.26_Pav.C3.B3n) ("butterfly orchid" or "poor man's orchid").

[image: *Schizanthus pinnatus* close-up]

> It is native to Chile but the plants are also cultivated as ornamentals. It is commonly known as the "small butterfly" ("mariposita") or "small, white butterfly" ("mariposita blanca").

**Description**

- Annual plant of 20-50 cm in height
- Stem: Glandulous-pubescent
- Leaves: 2.5-3 cm long; [pinnatisect](http://families.e-monocot.org/sites/families.e-monocot.org/files/pinnatisect.jpg) (divided into 6-8 pairs in oblong-linear segments, entire or separated).
- Flowers: white, pink or violet, 2-3 cm diameter, arranged in panniculate inflorescences, sometimes dichotomous.